# Undefined variable: "$navbar-height". error in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have just deployed the site and get following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in MainSite#home

Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".
```

I am not customizing anything and same code works on my local server but not on production server. I have been researching from last 5 days and read more than 10 articles but nothing has worked. Please provide your suggestion and here is the log trace:

```
rails_admin (0.8.1) app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/base/theming.scss:16
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/variable.rb:49:in `_perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in `visit_prop'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block in visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `visit_rule'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
sass-rails (5.0.4) lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
tilt (2.0.2) lib/tilt/template.rb:99:in `render'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:226:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:226:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:49:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:49:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:49:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:34:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:214:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:345:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:345:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:349:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:323:in `digest_path'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:311:in `asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:89:in `block in resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:88:in `resolve_asset_path'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:78:in `compute_asset_path'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:135:in `asset_path'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:292:in `image_path'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:176:in `favicon_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/main_site.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_main_site_html_erb___2923942470482702653_69847020960300'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
meta-tags (2.1.0) lib/meta_tags/controller_helper.rb:26:in `render_with_meta_tags'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.8.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
apartment (1.0.2) lib/apartment/reloader.rb:18:in `call'
simple_captcha2 (0.4.0) lib/simple_captcha/middleware.rb:26:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@redmine/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@redmine/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@redmine/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@redmine/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/home/root_zap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@redmine/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Use rails as a framework 
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'rails_admin_nestable', '~> 0.3.2'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use devise for authentication
gem 'devise'

# Use passenger for server
gem 'passenger'

# Use rails_admin for admin section
gem 'rails_admin'

# Use paperclip for image section
gem "paperclip"

# Use paperclip for image section
gem 'feedjira', '~> 1.6.0'

# Use simple_captcha2 for captcha image section
gem 'simple_captcha2', :require => 'simple_captcha'

# Use meta tags for seo section
gem 'meta-tags', :require => 'meta_tags'

# Use apartment for subdomain and database schema
gem 'apartment'

# Use whenever for CRON jobs
gem 'whenever', :require => false

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use ckeditor to display rich textare
gem "ckeditor"

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease.
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  # gem for deploying google maps in your application
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem 'gmaps4rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

Here is lock file (not working)

```
 remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    airbrussh (1.0.1)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    apartment (1.0.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.1.2, < 5.0)
      rack (>= 1.3.6)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capistrano (3.5.0)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      capistrano-harrow
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-harrow (0.3.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.6)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    ckeditor (4.1.6)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
    curb (0.9.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (4.0.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    feedjira (1.6.0)
      curb (~> 0.8)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
      sax-machine (~> 1.0)
    geocoder (1.3.4)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    meta-tags (2.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
    mime-types (3.0)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.3)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.1.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.3.6)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    passenger (5.0.27)
      rack
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    pg (0.18.4)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.1.2)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sax-machine (1.3.2)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    simple_captcha2 (0.4.0)
      rails (>= 4.1)
    spring (1.7.1)
    sprockets (3.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.10.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.2)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    whenever (0.9.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  apartment
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  bootstrap-sass
  capistrano-rails
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  feedjira (~> 1.6.0)
  geocoder
  gmaps4rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  meta-tags
  paperclip
  passenger
  pg
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  simple_captcha2
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  whenever
```

Comment: Please post the code in MainSite#home that is where the error is

Comment: Also post code in /theming.scss

Comment: take a look at the troubleshooting link below, let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the trace records I follow the below steps:
Copy local Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to production server and run the below command:

```
$ rvm use 2.1.3
$ rvm gemset empty
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Bootstrap? if so then which one?
If you are using bootstrap gem then omit all bootstrap gem and use files in assets.

Answer (score 2):

A general point: If it is working when environment is set to development, but not when set to production then it's an error caused due to the project being configured differently. In rails, the production configuration includes a bunch of optimisations such as how it builds the assets, or doesn't within production.

Beyond this, I would start to look first at what is different in their deployments. Are they both using the same gems (you can compare the Gemfile.lock), and check that there is nothing that is on your local machine that has not been checked into git/svn.

Also look at whether your system environments are similar (you can see why folks like containers/docker). Such as are you developing on mac but running on a windows host in production.

UPDATE: The above is general advice, below is advise based on the error.

Looking the rails_admin gem, you might want to look through the troubleshooting for bootstrap issues [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Troubleshoot#known-fix-for-twitter-bootstrap-rails). Let me know if none of those solutions fix your issue

Comment: I have try with development mode but still error occurs

Comment: I reset gem and copy gemlock file, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You need to precompile the assets check the development.rb file and include the all sass file

config.assets.precompile += %w( rails_admin/base/theming.scss );

add this line to development.rb file

Comment: I have resolved using gem reset but may be it your idea work :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have removed below line form my application code that work for me

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css)
```